Spivak Chapter 7, Problem-15

If $\phi$ is continuous and $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}=0=\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}$ then
(a) Prove that if $n$ is odd then there is a number $x$ such that $x^n+\phi(x)=0$

Proof: Since $\phi$ is continuous it must have an upper bound $N$ and a lower bound $M$. Since every number has an odd root it follows...$$x_{N}^n+N=0$$
$$x_{M}^n+M=0$$
for some $x_{N}$ and some $x_{M}$. Consider the interval $[x_{N},x_{M}]$ because $x^n$ is continuous it must take on every value between $x_{N}$ and $x_{M}$. Therefore there must be an $x$ such that $x^n+\phi(x)=0$ for every $x$ in the domain of $\phi$.

(b) Prove that if $n$ is even there is a number $y$ such that
$y^n+\phi(y)\le x^n+\phi(x)$

Lemma: If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then there is some $y$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f(y)\le f(x)$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$
If we let $f(x)=x^n$, it follows that $(f+\phi)(x)$ is continuous. It then follows from the lemma above that $$y^n+\phi(y)\le x^n+\phi(x)$$
is automatically true for some $y$. Q.E.D
Afterthoughts: I am slightly worried because I did not use the fact that, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}=0=\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}$, anywhere in my proof. This leads me to believe it's wrong, but I'm struggling to find an error. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Your first sentence is already false: the function $x\mapsto x$ is continuous but not bounded ...

Continous on an open doesn't specially gives you upper and lower bound. Instead use the fact that $\varphi$ is a small $o$ of $x^n$ at the infinities and thus $x^n+\phi(x)$ is $-\infty$ at $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ at $+\infty$.

@LL3.14 Oops...

You should model our arguments directly on Spivak’s proofs of the analogous results (proved in that chapter) for polynomials of odd and even degree. Indeed, this exercise is there to make sure you do understand those proofs.

While the answers I received were correct, they missed the mark pedologically speaking. After a couple days of review I believe I've formulated a far more insightful proof. Per the advice of Ted Shifrin I have modeled them in a similar fashion of the proofs to the analogous theorems in Chapter 7.

If $\phi$ is continuous and $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}=0=\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}$ then...


(a) Prove that if $n$ is odd then there is a number $x$ such that
$x^n+\phi(x)=0$

Let $f(x)=\phi(x)+x^n$
Since $\lim_{|x| \to \infty } \frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}=0$ from the definition it follows...
$$\forall \epsilon>0\exists N>0\forall x\in \mathbb{R}(|x|>N\Longrightarrow |\frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}|<\epsilon)$$
For $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ let $c$ be such an $N$. So $-\frac{1}{2}<\frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}<\frac{1}{2}$ for $|x|>c$ and which implies  $\frac{1}{2}<\frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}+1$. For $x_1>c$ we have...  $$f(x_1)=x_1^n(1+\frac{\phi(x_1)}{(x_1)^n})>\frac{x_1^n}{2}>0$$
for $x_2<-c$, since $n$ is odd we have
$$f(x_2)=x_2^n(1+\frac{\phi(x_2)}{(x_2)^n})<\frac{x_2^n}{2}<0$$
Since $f(x_1)>0>f(x_2)$ and $f$ is continuous there must be some $x$ in $[x_2,x_1]$ such that $f(x)=0$. We now move on to the second part of the problem.

(b) Prove that if $n$ is even there is a number $y$ such that
$y^n+\phi(y)\le x^n+\phi(x)$

Lemma: If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then there is some $y$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f(y)\le f(x)$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$
As from the previous problem. If $|x|>c$ then $\frac{1}{2}<\frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}+1$, this time since $n$ is even
$$f(x)=x^n(1+\frac{\phi(x)}{(x)^n})>\frac{x^n}{2}>0$$ for every $|x|>c$. Let $b>c$ be such a number that $b^n>2f(0)$. If $x\ge b$ then
$$f(x)>\frac{x^n}{2}\ge \frac{b^n}{2}>f(0)$$
Likewise, if $x\le -b$
$$f(x)>\frac{x^n}{2}\ge \frac{(-b)^n}{2}=\frac{(b)^n}{2}>f(0)$$
By using our Lemma; (1) If we consider the interval $[-b,b]$ then there is some $y$ in $[-b,b]$ such that for every $x$ in $[-b,b]$, $f(x)\ge f(y)$.  In particular $f(0)\ge f(y)$.
From previous results we know if $|x|\ge b$ then (2) $f(x)>f(0)\ge f(y)$
Combining (1) and (2) we see $f(x)\ge f(y)$ for every $x$
Q.E.D

Here is a sketch of a solution (a). I let the OP fill in the gaps.
Notice that for $x\neq0$
\begin{align}
\psi(x):= x^n+\phi(x)=x^n\Big(1+\frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}\Big)
\end{align}
The assumption $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}=0$ implies that
$\lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}1+\frac{\phi(x)}{x^n}=1>0$.

Thus, if $n$ is odd,
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\psi(x)=-\infty<\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\psi(x)=\infty$$
The conclusion follows from the intermediate value theorem.

On the other hand, if $n$ is even $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}\psi(x)=\infty$. The conclusion then follows immediately. For example, choose $a>0$ such that $\psi(x)>e^{|\psi(0)|}$ for all $|x|>a$.
On $[-a,a]$ $\psi$ has a minimum point, say $y$. Thus $\psi(x)\geq \psi(y)$ for all $|x|\leq a$. And for $|x|>a$,
$$\psi(x)>e^{|\psi(0)|}>|\psi(0)|\geq \psi(0)\geq \psi(y)$$



I sum up in an answer :
1st point
Continous on an open doesn't specially gives you upper and lower bound. Instead use the fact that $\varphi$ is a small $o$ of $x^n$ at the infinities and thus $x^n+\phi(x)$ is $-\infty$ at $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ at $+\infty$.
2nd point
The lemma 2 is valid for $f$ continous on an interval but $\mathbb{R}$ is not an interval but an open. So you can't use it. Instead consider the continuous function :
$$ g : x \to x^n + \phi(x) $$
considering $n$ is even, and initial limit conditions, gives limits at each $\pm \infty$ and then $g$ being continous you may end the exercise.

Observe that for $g(x)=f(x)+x^n$ we have $$\lim_{x\to \pm\infty}{g(x)\over x^n}=1$$ Therefore for $n$ odd $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}g(x)=\pm\infty $$ respectively, because $\lim_{x\to\pm \infty}x^n=\pm \infty$. By IMV the function $g(x)$ vanishes at some point.
If $n$ is even then $$\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}{g(x)}=\infty$$ and the conclusion $(b)$ follows.
